# Documents library wants to open Excel file in XLViewer

Tags: document-library, excel

We've added some Word and Excel documents, as well as PDFs to the default Documents library in a SharePoint 2010 publishing site. However, SharePoint wants to open the Excel files in the built-in viewer, which isn't what we want; we want it to simply point to the file. It generates this link in the document library:

```
http://vmdev95/lrc/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/lrc/Documents/hiring/Auto Enroll Benefits Form.xlsx&Source=http://vmdev95/lrc/Documents/Forms/AllItems.aspx?RootFolder%3D%252Flrc%252FDocuments%252Fhiring%26FolderCTID%3D0x01200067ED44E4B91D0B45883619F70B0513CE%26View%3D{5E32441D-302D-47EF-83C9-00F140B1DBAA}&DefaultItemOpen=1
```

We want just this:

```
/lrc/Documents/hiring/Auto Enroll Benefits Form.xlsx
```

How do you disable XLViewer feature? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the advanced settings in the document library.

There you have the option to open files in the browser or in the client. You most probably have *Browser* selected, go for *Client* here (or *Server Default* if the default is client).

Another setting which you might want to look at is under General Settings of the Web Application: You can choose to have Permissive or Strict file handling.

Comment: Is there a way to do this for the mobile view? I have a customer that wants the document to be downloaded and open to their device instead of viewing the document in excel services. This work for documents that have a file extension of .xls.

Comment: You should ask a new question about this. Mobile views are a totally different animal: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff393832.aspx

Comment: What to do if I've set Client as default, but excel files still are opening in XLViewer?